# Objects in groups are not selectable

Tags: fabricjs

Currently I try to create a fabric.Group which contains several fabric.Circle's. 
Each circle should be selectable and draggable.

Objects that are added directly to the canvas can be selected by default. But when I add circles to a group, they are not selectable.

I was only able to make them selectable when I add the circles to the group *and* additionally to the canvas. But that looks a little cluttered to me. I mean... I don't need to add the children of a group additionally to the canvas to make them painted, but I need to add them additionally to the canvas to make the selection work?

Is that behavior intended, am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

```
jQuery(function() {
   var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('playground');

   // First the selectable circle:
   var singleCirlce = new fabric.Circle({top: 100, left: 100, radius: 30, fill : 'red'});
   canvas.add(singleCirlce); 

   //second the circle in a group that is not selectable:
   var group = new fabric.Group();
   var groupedCircle = new fabric.Circle({top: 200, left: 200, radius: 30, fill : 'blue'});
   group.add(groupedCircle);
   canvas.add(group);
});
```

Comment: This is by design. The group is an entity on its own. It acts the same way as any other object does, which is why it can be selected, scaled, moved, rotated, etc. If you need to work with objects separately, you should just add them separately to canvas. Why need for a group?

Comment: I would like to create a scene graph where groups act like a node in a graph and objects act like leafs in the graph. Or you could also say, I expected Group and Object to be the parts of a composite pattern.

Comment: For example: I want to create a ButtonBar which consists of a Rect as a background and 3 Circles over the background. The Circles should behave like Buttons and should be clickable. The Circles and the Backgroud are children of a group, so that the complete ButtonBar can be moved, or scaled or something else.

Comment: What I need is an Object, that can receive events on its own, even when it is part of a group. But when the whole Group is scaled, the scale should also apply for all its children.

Comment: I see what you mean. This functionality is marked as a possible feature — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/485

Comment: Yes, that's it. I really appreciate that you react to your users ideas. Is it realistic that this feature might come in short time?

Comment: Honestly, unlikely to come anytime soon UNLESS someone contributes it. I'm open to including it in Fabric.

Comment: Well, that could be me :-) I'm already trying to track that down with a debugger in Chrome... but some advise would be appreciated... Currently I'm facing another problem in that context. The Group is only clickable if it's children are added to the Group via the constructor. If they are added via the add()-method the whole group is painted, but it's not selectable... but that is annother issue, I think...

Comment: You need to use `addWithUpdate`; it's probably just not updating dimensions (which are 0/0 from the start)

Comment: Alright, addWithUpdate() solves that. I will try to contribute to your project by adding events for child-objects of groups. Is there an adequate communication channel for this? Maybe on github?

Comment: Yes, github issue is definitely more appropriate :)

Comment: I have commented the issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is: create un-grouped version of grouped elements, such as:

```
objects = {...};
canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Have a common `groupId` for each object, listen to:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function() {...});
```

If any of the objects are moved move all the objects in that `groupId` accordingly.

`note:` this is just a theory, I haven't implemented it yet, and I'm unsure how would it react if multiple objects are selected at the same time.